# xAxis auto label dropping has stopped working after upgrading to Highcharts 5.0.8

Tags: highcharts

The label looks good in Highcharts 4 but after upgrading to Highcharts 5 I started to Ellipses.

The `xAxis.label` property looks something like this. Is there any way I can force the label to render horizontally and drop if there is not enough room for them to be rendered ? I can't use `step:1`

```
 labels: {
    rotation: 0

  }
```

[Highcharts-4](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshya_8/a8g87gm8/9/)

[Highcharts-5](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshya_8/a8g87gm8/10/)

[image]

Rotation value I'm using for different Label Angle options are below:

- Auto - I'm using `autoRatate:[-10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -60, -70, -80, -90]`
- --  : `rotate:0` -- I've problem with this option
- /// : `rotate:-45`
- ||| : `rotate:90`
- \\ : `rotate:45`

Comment: How about staggerLines? http://jsfiddle.net/a8g87gm8/15/

Comment: Thanks. Setting the value for either `step` or `staggerLines` would solve the problem but it has to be dynamic ( taken care by Highcharts ). If we look at the my **Highcahrts-4** demo it is actually setting the  `staggerLines`  dynamically.

Comment: I think you may be out of luck here.  They took automatic staggerLines out of the code in version 4.1 (12/2015) when they added in auto rotate.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird  Thanks ! I spent hours comparing the behaviour between different versions of Highcharts. Is there any way to calculate step value based on the number of labels? The only thing I’m looking for is a way to drop the labels automatically when rotation:0

Comment: In the 4.0 source there is a function called getOffset.  It has how they used to calculate the autoStaggerLines.  You could replicate that logic.  The issue is that category names or varying lengths, so you have to figure out based on the chart width, how you can make them fit with no overlap.  In my opinion, it's not a great user experience to only see some of the labels on a category axis.  How can the user guess what is missing?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the function. I agree the user would not know which labels are missing but at least seeing some labels are better than all the labels being truncated. I have also posted another question about how to calculate the `step` size automatically based on the chart size and number of labels , you can check the screenshots here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935924/is-there-any-way-to-automatically-calculate-the-axis-labels-step-size-in-highch

Comment: Have you thought about using rotation?

Comment: That's a good point but in our app we are proving 5 different options to rotate the labels. *Auto*, *Horizontal*, *Rotate 45* , *Rotate 90* and *Rotate -45*. I'm using `autoRotate` for *Auto* option and `rotate:0` for Horizontal. So here I'm forcing the labels to render horizontally.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird I have updated the question with all the label angle options.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `staggerLines` can take care of this, but needs to be set manually.

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/a8g87gm8/14/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.staggerLines

Comment: In my case `xAxis` data changes dynamically so I can't set the `staggerLines` manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the issue by calculating the `step` size dynamically based on the width of the `xAxis`.

Here is my solution:

```
 /**
 * Automatically calculate the step size based on the width of the container.
 * 1. Find the width of the xAxis
 * 2. Get the width of the label, which in our case is 80px.
 * 3. Find the no of labels that can be displayed on the xAxis.
 * 4. Find the max no of labels by iterating through all the xAxis.
 * 5. To find the final step size by dividing value from step 4 / step 3.
 *
 * @returns {number}
 * @private
 */

  _getLabelStep: function () {
    var xAxisWidth, labelWidth, labelsToDisplay, noOfTicks, step;
    xAxisWidth = this._getXAxisWidth();
    labelWidth = this.AXIS_LABEL_WIDTH;
    labelsToDisplay = Math.floor(xAxisWidth / labelWidth);
    noOfTicks = this._getMaxNoOfTicks();
    step = Math.floor(noOfTicks / labelsToDisplay);
    return isNaN(step) ? 0 : step;
  },

/**
 * Iterate through all the xAxis' and find the max no of ticks (labels)'.
 * @returns {number}
 * @private
 */
  _getMaxNoOfTicks : function () {
    var i ,maxNoOfTicks =0 ;
    if(this.chart && this.chart.xAxis){
        for(i=0 ; i<this.chart.xAxis.length ; i ++){
            if(this.chart.xAxis[i].dataMax && this.chart.xAxis[i].dataMax > maxNoOfTicks ){
                maxNoOfTicks = this.chart.xAxis[i].dataMax;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxNoOfTicks;

  },

/**
 * returns the width of the xAxis.
 * @private
 */
  _getXAxisWidth : function () {
    if(this.chart && this.chart.xAxis && this.chart.xAxis.length>0){
        return this.chart.xAxis[0].len;
    }
  }
```

- Call the function `_getLabelStep` and set the label `step` size.

  `labels:{step : this._getLabelStep()}
   style:{width : 80px}`
- To be able to calculate the `step` size based on the `xAxis` container, We must have to have defined label width. i.w `80px` in my case.