# Is there any way to automatically calculate the axis labels' step size in Highcharts ?

Tags: highcharts

I have 1000~ data labels on the xAxis and finding a way to automatically calculate the `step` based on the number of data labels and size of the charts.

Based on the documentation , if I do not set the `step` property of `xAxis.labels` , it will be calculated automatically, But in my case it is not.

- Current output:

[image: Current problem]

- Expected output:

[image: Expected Output]

Currenlty the labels look as shown in the image. I'd expect the labels to drop automatically and do not show the ellipses. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

-I'm using **Highcharts-5.0.8**

Comment: Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try to create a live example of the issue - your starting point can be this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-step/

Comment: @morganfree This question is a part of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934154/xaxis-auto-label-dropping-has-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-highcharts-5-0. ( which has fiddle demos)